# Saving the output/user input of a certain If statement(VB)

Tags: vb.net

I want to save the output/user input of an If statement, yet variables within the code don't seem to work on the specified line that I need.

```
Dim timer As Integer = 0
Dim answer As String = 0
Do
    timer = timer + 1
    Thread.Sleep(1000)
    If Console.KeyAvailable Then
        If Console.ReadKey(True).KeyChar = "q" Then Exit Do
    End If
Loop
Console.WriteLine(timer)
Console.Read()
```

I need what the user inputs after the .KeyChar statement. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Divide that line in two or more, assigning the console.readline to a variable:

```
Dim userKey as ConsoleKeyInfo
...
If Console.KeyAvailable Then
    userKey = Console.ReadKey()
    If userKey.Key.ToString = "q" Then Exit Do
End If
...
```

Take a look at [MSDN - ReadKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/471w8d85(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) for more detailed info